# Yii 1.1.14 with Composer autoload

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

I have my composer.json file at the root, which looks like this (after following [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/392/creating-yii-applications-with-composer/)):

```
{
  "repositories": [{
    "type":"composer",
    "url": "http://packages.phundament.com"
  }],

  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "yiisoft/yii": "1.1.*",
    "yiiext/migrate-command": "0.7.2",
    "thyseus/yii-user-management": "0.8"
  },

  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "config": "./" }
  },

  "scripts": {
      "pre-install-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::preInstall",
      "post-install-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::postInstall",
      "pre-update-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::preUpdate",
      "post-update-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::postUpdate",
      "post-package-install": ["config\\ComposerCallback::postPackageInstall"],
      "post-package-update": ["config\\ComposerCallback::postPackageUpdate"]
  }
}
```

My config/console.php also includes the following:

```
'params' => array(
    'composer.callbacks' => array(
        // args for Yii command runner
        'yiisoft/yii-install' => array('yiic', 'webapp', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'),
        'post-update' => array('yiic', 'migrate'),
        'post-install' => array('yiic', 'migrate'),
    ),
),
```

I'm getting the following error, however, when I try to run `composer install`:

> Class config\ComposerCallback is not autoloadable, can not call pre-update-cmd script

I realize it's probably something small that I've forgotten, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So there is a file in the path `config/ComposerCallback.php` that contains a `namespace config; class ComposerCallback {}`?

Comment: I presumed that it was something made by Yii, as the guide doesn't mention it at all (my first time writing a Yii app).

Comment: The guide has a link to a demo file content that seems to do some basic stuff. I think you should copy it.

Comment: As far as I can tell I did copy it...

Comment: But if it isn't in the right place, you get an error like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using an early version of Phundament, like [this one](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/5165083d793074e3de49130e89bd83e2735823a3/config/ComposerCallback.php).

Your composer callbacks are trying to call the methods in the `ComposerCallback` class, which - in your case - should be in `<project-folder>/config`.

You can use the file from above and place it there or grab [a more recent version](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/master/src/Phundament/ComposerCallback.php) from phundament/app and place the file into `<project-folder>/src/Phundament` and update your root `composer.json` [autoloading section](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/a6f6d07aa68094473b7d2d8c322602f5e9c63066/composer.json#L83) to match the new file location.